# Building a multi class image classifier

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I built my first CNN after watching a YouTube tutorial.

I am getting good accuracy when playing around with two classes of data.

As soon as I introduce a third, the accruacy drops to around 0.32. As I go on increasing the classes, the accuracy continues to fall.

Does anyone know why that could be happening?

```
import os
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

DATA_DIR = '/home/devesh/Desktop/neural_networks_practice'
CATEGORIES = ['Car', 'Bike']
training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES: 
        path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), 0)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (50,50))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

create_training_data()

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)

len(training_data)

X = []
y = []  

for features, label in training_data:
        X.append(features)
        y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 50, 50, 1)
y = np.array(y)

import pickle

pickle_out = open('X.pickle','wb')
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close() 

pickle_out = open('y.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close() 

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

pickle_in = open('X.pickle','rb')
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in = open('y.pickle','rb')
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X / 255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split = 0.1, epochs = 20)
```

Above is the script which specifies two data classes. With this, I get acuraccy of up to 95%.

But as said, introducing another class drops that to 30%

Comment: How are you introducing the third category? Your model output and loss function seem very specific to performing binary classification.

Comment: Got it sir. Getting into DL, so excuse my ignorance kindly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a Sigmoid activation function, which is proper only for binary classification. You need to replace it with a Softmax activation, which instead is meant for multi-class classification.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got it. I am getting into DL for CV and can't get myself to get hands on some good resources for learning it. Thanks for helping out again!

Comment: Youtube, Brown Lee tutorial on Machine learning Mastery and Toward data science are good starting points. Also, consider to explore the documentations of the libraries you use, Keras is not the best in my opinion, but in the pytorch documentation for example they add also description of each activation usage purpose ( https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html ).